# PhP MySQL NOT LIKE does not return the correct value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, compare, sql-like

I'm trying to query result using `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE` in PHP & MySQL.

I have a table `BeaconEvent` with 2 columns: `BeaconID` and `EventID`;

Table **BeaconEvent**:

```
BeaconID        EventID
-------------------------
5DBA-BC5B       Time0003
5DBA-BC5B       NLB0001
5264-9028       NLB0004
1F8B-35E6       NLB0005
```

When I run the MySQL command to select all `BeaconID` with `EventID` is a specific value, the query works fine but when I run the query to select `BeaconID` with `EventID` is not equal to specify value, it return all the `BeaconID` (which is not right, should exclude the `BeaconID` which has `EventID` equal to specific value)

Example query that works:

```
SELECT BeaconEvent.BeaconID 
FROM BeaconEvent 
WHERE BeaconEvent.EventID = "Time0003"

SELECT BeaconEvent.BeaconID 
FROM BeaconEvent 
WHERE BeaconEvent.EventID LIKE "Time0003"
```

And these queries do not work:

```
SELECT BeaconEvent.BeaconID 
FROM BeaconEvent 
WHERE BeaconEvent.EventID != "Time0003"

SELECT BeaconEvent.BeaconID 
FROM BeaconEvent 
WHERE BeaconEvent.EventID <> "Time0003"

SELECT BeaconEvent.BeaconID 
FROM BeaconEvent 
WHERE BeaconEvent.EventID NOT LIKE "Time0003"

SELECT BeaconEvent.BeaconID 
FROM BeaconEvent 
WHERE BeaconEvent.EventID NOT LIKE "%Time0003%"
```

Any suggestion to compare value which is not equal to specific one? Thanks in advance

Comment: `5DBA-BC5B` is duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data has the same `BeaconID` for two values:

```
BeaconID        EventID
5DBA-BC5B       Time0003       
5DBA-BC5B       NLB0001
```

Your queries work perfectly as they should:

```
SELECT BeaconEvent.BeaconID 
FROM BeaconEvent 
WHERE BeaconEvent.EventID <> "Time0003";

SELECT BeaconEvent.BeaconID 
FROM BeaconEvent 
WHERE BeaconEvent.EventID = "Time0003";
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01cf2/3/1)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════╗
║ BeaconID  ║
╠═══════════╣
║ 5DBA-BC5B ║
║ 5264-9028 ║
║ 1F8B-35E6 ║
╚═══════════╝

╔═══════════╗
║ BeaconID  ║
╠═══════════╣
║ 5DBA-BC5B ║
╚═══════════╝
```

---

If you want to exclude it(and you are sure your data is correct) you can use:

```
SELECT BeaconEvent.BeaconID 
FROM BeaconEvent 
WHERE BeaconEvent.BeaconID <> (SELECT BeaconID 
                               FROM BeaconEvent
                               WHERE EventID = 'Time0003')
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01cf2/4/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════╗
║ BeaconID  ║
╠═══════════╣
║ 5264-9028 ║
║ 1F8B-35E6 ║
╚═══════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your resoond, I'll Try it. But I have a middle problem now to join 3 table. Another table With Event ID is primary key and contain all the event detail. This is my query, don't know what going worng: SELECT Event.EventID,Event.EventTitle,Event.EventDesc,Event.EventStartTime,Event.EventEndTime FROM Event JOIN BeaconEvent JOIN Beacon AS BeaconEvent.BeaconID=Beacon.BeaconID && Event.EventID = BeaconEvent.EventID WHERE Event.EventEndTime>=NOW()

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh So this is [XY question](http://xyproblem.info/). The real question is not about wrong behaviuor of <>, NOT LIKE but your specific query. I suggest asking new question with full data sample, http://sqlfiddle.com demo and desired output.